# Drawing graphs based on data in the database

Tags: python, django

I need to draw graphs based on data from models. How can this be done?

Model

```
adress = models.ForeignKey(Parking, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
carnumber = models.CharField(max_length=150)
amountoftime = models.IntegerField()
price = models.FloatField()
telephone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
email = models.EmailField(null=True,blank=True )
datetimepaidparking = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
expirationdate = models.DateField(null=True)
expirationtime = models.TimeField(null=True)
enddateandtime = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
```

I need to create a schedule for a certain period of time(month, day, week)

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js might be great graphing front end solution.
You can pass data to the template using ‘json-script’ tag